# Error while checking existence of a file in shell script

Tags: bash

I wrote a script to check if a given file exists or not ( i am considering only regular files )
It displays opposite, that is, if file exists then "not found" and "file found" if file doesn't exists.
Have i messed up the if else ?
Please tell me how to rectify it.

```
#! /bin/bash
is_file_exists(){
 local file="$1"
 if  [[ -f "$file" ]]
 then
  return 1
 else
 return 0
 fi
}

if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]
then
 echo "enter a file name" 
 exit
fi

if ( is_file_exists "$1" )
then
  echo "file found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: You have the `return 0` and `return 1` around the wrong way in your `is_file_exists` function, and you should use: `if is_file_exists "$1"`, i.e. no parentheses.

Comment: @aditya feel free to accept one of the answer below if you think that it answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, firstly, you're not checking for existence (`-e`); you're checking that it exists *and* that it's a regular file.

Secondly, you're returning 0 (success) if it *doesn't* exist.

But since the return value of a function is that of the last command, there's no need for the `if`/`else` at all:

```
is_file_exists() {
   test -f "$1"
}
```

---

Re-written program (as portable shell, since it doesn't need anything Bash-specific):

```
#!/bin/sh

regular_file_exists() {
   test -f "$1"
}

# Is it used correctly?
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "enter a file name" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if regular_file_exists "$1"
then
  echo "file found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: Is it the fact that the function is returning 0 when [[ -f file_name ]] evaluates to true ( that is the file exists ) and 1 otherwise?

Comment: Your function was the wrong way around - returning 1 (false) when the file exists, when you should return 0, and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment said, you have the `return 0` and `return 1` around the wrong way in your `is_file_exists` function, and you should use: `if is_file_exists "$1"`, i.e. no parentheses.

Shell `if` statements test success or failure of the given command.  Success is defined as a returned value of zero.  So maybe you had the returns around that way because you might have come from C, Java, or a similar language where zero is *false*.  Think in terms of success or failure rather than true or false.

I have suggested a few other tweaks, including consistent indentation:

```
#! /bin/bash
is_file_exists(){

    local file="$1"

    # [ (test) could have been used here
    # Is the name given a regular file?        
    if  [[ -f $file ]]     # quotes not required with [[ (but are with [ )
    then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

# Use (( )) for arithmetic comparisons
if (( $# == 0 ))
then
    echo "enter a file name" >&2       # error messages should go to stderr
    exit
fi

# Delimit filenames on display, shows unintended whitespace
if is_file_exists "$1"
then
    echo "'$1' file found"
else
    echo "'$1' not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep the "inverse" logic of your `is_file_exists()` function then you can do the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
is_file_exists(){
 local file="$1"
 if  [[ -f "$file" ]]
 then
  return 1
 else
  return 0
 fi
}

if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]
then
 echo "enter a file name" 
 exit
fi

is_file_exists "$1"
retVal=$?

if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "file found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

This stores the return value of the function into the `retVal` variable and checks its value to provide the desired output.

Also, as suggested by @Toby, another solution would be (skipping the fuction):

```
if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]
then
 echo "enter a file name" 
 exit
fi

if ! is_file_exists "$1"; then
  echo "file found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```